# complex analysis and holomorphic extension in union of connected open sets

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U_1⊆U_2⊆U_3⊆...⊆ \mathbb{C}$ be connected open sets and let $U=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^∞U_i$. Let $f$ be holomorphic on $U$. Suppose for each $U_i$, $f|_{U_i}$ has a holomorphic anti-derivative on $U_i$. Prove that f has a holomorphic anti-derivative on all of U.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma $ be any closed path in $U$. Then $\gamma$ is contained in $U_n$ for some $n$ and this implies that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz=0$. [The integral of any derivative over a closed path is $0$]. Now use a standard argument to construct a primitive in $U$: fix $z_0$ and define $F(z)$ as the integral of $f$ over any path from $z_0$ to $z$. Show that this is independent of the path and verify that $F'(z)=f(z)$.